# When should I typedef struct vs. pointer to struct?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, abstract-data-type

I'm not an expert on lower-level non-object-oriented programming languages, and I'm in the middle of writing some C code for a project at work. I'm trying to create some decent abstract data types to work with, and Googling around made me realize that people use struct-based ADT's in two ways. Some people define a data type as a struct:

```
typedef struct adt {
    //content here
} adt;
```

and expose it to the world in the header file.

Others define a data type as a *pointer* to struct:

```
// In .c file:
typedef struct adt_s {
    //content here
} adt_s, *adt;


// In .h file:
typedef struct adt_s *adt;
```

I understand that this approach allows you to typedef a struct without giving the outside world any knowledge of what's inside this struct, so programmers can *only* use functions supplied in the same header file to operate on this data type.

Are there an other reasons to pick on over the other? Is there a general "rule of thumb" for when the define ADT's as structs and when do we define them as pointers to structs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can forward declare a struct without typedef too - the only distinctions are:

- whether the interface looks cleaner with or without the keyword `struct`
- whether the interface looks cleaner with or without the explicit pointer `*`

Eg.

```
struct S1;
typedef struct S2 S2;
typedef struct S3_s *S3;

void foo1(struct S1 *arg);
void foo2(S2 *arg);
void foo3(S3);
```

Obviously this only applies for forward-declared structures in an interface header.

If you're not hiding the structure implementation in the first place, choosing between `S1` and `S2` is a matter of preference (or consistency). I wouldn't use `S3` unless it's a really opaque/hidden type.

Personal preference would be to use `S1` (explicit struct keyword) for big/complex aggregates, and `S2` for small structs you might treat like values and not always pass by pointer.  YMMV.

Comment: For readability purposes maybe it's better to write `typedef struct S3_s* S3` instead of `typedef struct S3_s *S3`, no ?

Comment: @Eregrith: if you go by formal language semantics, `typedef struct S3_s *S3` says that the declarator `*S3` has type `struct S3_s` and storage class `typedef`, so putting the asterisk with the identifier is actually idiomatic; however, putting the asterisk with the type is more in tune with how many (most?) people think about declarations; as far as I'm concernded, both versions are fine as long as you're consistent...

Comment: I just selected that spacing for consistency with the OP, since I can see benefits either way.

Answer (score 1):

The decision to hide or not to hide rests entirely with you as the designer of your library. If you would like to reserve the right to change your `struct` at will in the future, you should not be exposing any of its members to "the world". If you are providing a `struct` as means to communicate with your library in the first place (for example, a `struct` representing a point in 3D), then you cannot hide its members from the world, as it would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

read the Linus Torvalds [post](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle)
Chapter 5: Typedefs